Reference request continuous embedding $W^{1,2}(0,\infty;H) \hookrightarrow L^\infty(0,\infty;H)$
I need a reference for the continuous embedding $W^{1,2}(0,\infty;H) \hookrightarrow L^\infty(0,\infty;H)$, where $H$ is some separable Hilbert space. I believe this is true and the embedding constant should be $1$ (in the scalar case this can be proven via the Fourier transform as in the answer to the post Embedding Sobolev $H^1$ into $L^\infty$ space, I don't see that anything would go wrong in the Bochner case either). I need to use this result in a paper, but can't find a citeable reference in any of my books. Any hints are welcome.

Maybe cross-post this on MathOverflow.

First let me prove this for $H =\mathbb R$. Let $u\in H^1(\mathbb R)\setminus \{0\}$. Let $L>0$ and set $I=(a,a+1)$.
Take $x,y \in I$. Then
$$
u(y)^2 - u(x)^2 = 2\int_x^y u(s)u'(s)ds \le 2\int_x^y|u(s)|\cdot |u'(s)|ds  \le  2\|u\|_{L^2(I)}\|u'\|_{L^2(I)}.
$$
Integrating with respect to $x$ yields
$$
Lu(y)^2 \le \|u\|_{L^2(I)} + 2 L\|u\|_{L^2(I)}\|u'\|_{L^2(I)}.
$$
Taking the supremum in $y$ gives
$$
\|u\|_{L^\infty(I)}^2 \le L^{-1} \|u\|_{L^2(I)}^2 + 2 \|u\|_{L^2(I)}\|u'\|_{L^2(I)}\\
\le L^{-1} \|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2 + 2 \|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}\|u'\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}
$$
Since
$$
\|u\|_{L^\infty( \mathbb R)}^2
=\sup_{a\in \mathbb R} \|u\|_{L^\infty((a,a+L))} 
\le L^{-1} \|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2 + 2 \|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}\|u'\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}.
$$
we get the claim for the infinite interval by passing to the limit $L\to \infty$ and using
$$
2 \|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}\|u'\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)} \le 
\|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2+\|u'\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2 = \|u\|_{H^1(\mathbb R)}^2.
$$
(I do not see a better proof for the embedding constant $=1$.)

In the general case, where $H$ is a Hilbert space, the
above proof can be repeated line by line:
$$
\|u(y)\|_H^2 \le \|u(x)\|_H^2 + 2\int_x^y \|u(s)\|_H\|u'(s)\|_Hds .
$$
Then integrate in $y$, take supremum over $x$, slide the small intervall along the real axis.

Thanks for your effort, but I had already linked a proof for the scalar case when posting and I am really only need a citeable reference, so this is not really what I was looking for.

I do not know a reference either, and as the transfer of the result from $\mathbb R$ to general $H$ is so trivial, there might be no reference at all.
